# How to use Lightsail load balancers globally instead of per region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, cloudflare, amazon-elb, amazon-lightsail

My web app's DNS is managed by Cloudflare. I have created a CNAME record that points to a Lightsail load balancer DNS. It works fine.

The load balancer is created in a specific region. Ideally I want a load balancer that sends traffic to instances that are in different regions: Germany, Austrailia and USA for example.

Do I have to use Cloudflare load balancer instead? it seems to allow dispatching of traffic to origins based in different geographical locations.

Distribution/CDN is not a solution as some of the content will not be cached (videos for streaming). If I want low latency I need origins close to visitors.

Comment: Load Balancers in AWS a region bound. They can load balance connections between availability zones but not between regions.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi , precisely this is a problem. I don't make localized web apps. I serve pages globally. I see that AWS can do what I need using Route 53 and Global Accelerator. Another solution is to use a Cloudflare load balancer.